# How to get access to all cells at the Method didSelectItemAtIndexPath() in a UICollectionViewController (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

how can set values of any cell in my collection view at didSelectItemAtIndexPath. So i want to change the border color of all other cells to black expect the cell the user clicked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by keeping a reference for selection and index

```
var isSelected:Bool = false;
var index: Int;
```

and in didSelectItemAtIndexPath change the isselected property to true and keep the index path row value in index then reload the collection view

and when you populate your cell add the condition

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   if(isSelected && indexPath.Row != index )
   {
      // change the color to the black
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code iterates through the tableview sections, and each sections's rows. It compares the indexPath of each row to the indexPath of the selected cell, and if they don't match, allows you to do what you need to do to the cell.

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfSections]; ++i)
{
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; ++j)
    {
        NSIndexPath *cellIdxPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i];

        // indexPath represents the currently selected row
        if (indexPath != cellIdxPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIdxPath];
            // do whatever you need to do to the cell
        }
    }
}
```